# How to connect a pod via pod-name which is running in different AKS cluster?

Tags: azure-aks

I have two aks cluster setup:
A. My application
B. Monitoring

I have configured my application to expose JMX stats via prometheus and can successfully fetch the pod-name/metrics as long as I am on the same cluster.

My requirement is that I want to set this pod as a target in my prometheus server which is running on cluster B.

I have tried setting up vnet peering between the two clusters which allows me to reach the cluster A pod from Cluster B via pod IP.
example: pod-ip:9090(jmx-port)/metrics.
However, since the pod ip is dynamic I was looking for a way to resolve the request via pod-name.
Any information will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of Kubernetes DNS-based service discovery and CoreDNS customization

- Create a Headless Service
- Configure CoreDNS Customization
- Update CoreDNS Deployment

find the documentation below

[Customize CoreDNS in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/coredns-custom)

[VNet Peering documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview)